# Sub menu for the menu bar ?

Tags: menu-bar

Ive got various menu bar icons all of which i use, but they are beginning to take up too much room. Is there a way i can get them all to sit under a sub menu in the menu bar ? Im running OSX 10.10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Bartender**](https://www.macbartender.com) is an app for rearranging menu bar items and creates a separate menu bar for more.

Bartender 2's menu bar is submenu-style.

[image]

Bartender 3 integrates the submenu into the position of the existing menu bar, with a toggle.

> [image]
>
> [image]